# move files to subfolder ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I created a ssis package to move backup files from c: location to E location:

```
source file path: C:\Backup\A\xxx.bak
destination file path: E:\DB Backups\A\xxx.bak
```

I used foreachloop container and created two variables: `sourcefileV` and `destinationV` and used file system task to rename file. The package works however after moved the file to destination, the file is not in subfolder `E:\DB Backups\A`, it's in `E:\DB Backups`. I have to manually cut and move it to the subfolder. Is there any way to directly move file to the destination subfolder in ssis package?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can create two variables `@[User::DestinationFolder]` and `@[User::SourceFolder]`.

```
@[User::SourceFolder] = C:\Backup\
@[User::DestinationFolder] = E:\DB Backups\
```

And you can use the following expression to create the destination folder path.

```
@[User::DestinationFolder] +  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@[User::SourceFileV],@[User::SourceFolder],""),1, LEN(REPLACE(@[User::SourceFileV],@[User::SourceFolder],"")) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::SourceFileV]),"\\",1))
```

And you can use the following expression to get the destination file path

```
@[User::DestinationFolder] + REPLACE(@[User::SourceFileV],@[User::SourceFolder],"")
```

First, you have to add an `Execute File System Task` to create the destination directory. Then you have to add a second `Execute File System Task` to copy the file.

Comment: Thanks for responding my question. I already find a way to fix the issue.

Comment: I used foreach loop container and file system task to move file not rename file also modified the configuration of foreach loop container. It works well. Thanks for your input :)